# Lookup compressor/filter friendly name from FOURCC ID in Delphi 6 application?

Tags: delphi, compression, directshow, vfw, fourcc

I have a Delphi 6 application that asks the user to select an audio and video compressor using AVISaveOptions().  I then store the FOURCC IDs of each selection in a data file.  I want to look up the Filter friendly name for each selection using the FOURCC ID belonging to each compressor/filter , so I can show the user their current choices at a later time with the compressor/filter friendly name showing next to the selected FOURCC IDs.  How can I do this?

Note I just want to show the user the same long form name that shows in the AVISaveOptions() dialog box that prompts the user for a selection by offering them a list box with the friendly names in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ICOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) opens driver for the given `FourCC`, then [`ICGetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you [`ICINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with descriptions.